# object in python

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I'm trying to exract the proper noun from executive sentences of a tagged corpus. When i run the code it only shows the list of the proper noun of 1st couple of sentences and then it stops and gives the following error:

```
          Traceback (most recent call last):
          print(list(words4))
          TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

The code:

```
      #extracting 
      def noun(sen):
          for t in range(len(sen)):
              if (sen[t].split('/')[1].lower() == 'np'):
                  w=sen[t].split('/')
                  return w

      if __name__ == '__main__':
          import nltk
          from nltk.corpus import brown
          f = brown.raw('ca01')
          print f
          mylist = []
          #splitting 
          sentences = splitParagraphIntoSentences(f)
          for s in sentences:
              mylist.append(s.strip())

          for i in mylist:
              print i

          for s in range(len(mylist)):
              words1 = mylist[s].split()
              words2 = mylist[s+1].split()
              words3= noun(words1)
              words4= noun(words2)
              print(list(words3))
              print(list(words4))
```

how to solve this error. Thanks.

Comment: Your `noun()` function can return `None` (if the code inside the `if` statement is never reached), and `None` cannot be iterated over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making two errors here:

1. "NP" isn't the only noun-phrase that NLTK uses. It also uses "NNP" and some others. You'll need to look into the tagset to figure out what there is. But I don't know what you're aiming for right now, so looking for just "np" may not be entirely wrong.
2. Your `noun(sen)` function doesn't **always** return something. It only returns if it find a word tagged "np" in your sentence. Now while it is a reasonable assumption that every sentence has a noun, consider that NLTK is not state-of-the-art and may therefore miss out on some nouns from time to time. Also, like I mentioned in (1), NLTK may also tag words with "NNP", so watch out.

To rectify this problem, try the following `noun(sen)` function (slightly modified version of yours:

```
def noun(sen):
    for t in range(len(sen)):
        if (sen[t].split('/')[1].lower() == 'np'):
            w=sen[t].split('/')
            return w
    return []
```

PS: please try to not use single-space indenting. It's not the best style and makes the eyes hurt